# lumen illuminate/validation validator goes wrong with integer rule

Tags: laravel-5, lumen

I recently met an issue with validator (illuminate/validation) under Lumen (5.4.6) (Laravel Components 5.4.*). It seems like the integer rule doesn't work.

I used Paw(or postman) to send companyName with type string and it can pass the validation and 'here i am' can printed out. Even a boolean type, let's say (boolean)companyName=TRUE can pass the validation. Have you met the same issue? this bug is quite obvious but I didn't find the similar discussion on google.

I also tested the string rule  'required|string|min:1' and it works accordingly, neither integer nor boolean parameters can pass the validation.

[code screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPlSV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel/Lumen makes use of PHP [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function for `integer` rule validation:

Class **Illuminate\Validation\Concerns\ValidatesAttributes**:

```
protected function validateInteger($attribute, $value)
{
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false;
}
```

As mentioned in the docs:

> Note that scalar values are converted to string internally before they are filtered.

So boolean `true` is converted to string `1` internally and therefore passes validation.

It's not considered a bug, but an implementation detail.